# Error in "p1"/"p2" : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

```
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
p1 <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(linewidth = 0.5) + 
  ggtitle("Old default")

p2 <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf() + 
  ggtitle("New default")

p1/p2
```

---

Error in p1/p2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

---

Not running. What should I do?
What should I fix?

I have no idea...

..

Comment: You are dividing two plots?

Comment: if you are trying to stack the plot you need to load the patchwork library first. Try adding `library(patchwork)` to the beginning of your script

Comment: Also for future questions it would be helpful if you stated what exactly you are trying to do and give a minimal reporducible example